# Make dictionary of objects create only the object for the specified key

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a `Dictionary` that takes an enum value as the key and returns an object as the value. The object constructors involve calling a method that can take a very long time and consume a lot of memory. Right now, each possible object in the dictionary is created, even if only one is needed. Is there a way to only create the object specified by the key?

```
private DataPreparer SetUpOuDataPreparer()
{
    Scope = _activeDirectoryScope.Context;
    var activeDirectorySearcher = new ActiveDirectorySearcher(
        _activeDirectoryScope);
    var ouDataPreparers = new Dictionary<QueryType, DataPreparer>
    {
        [OuComputers] = new DataPreparer
        {
            Data = activeDirectorySearcher.GetOuComputerPrincipals(),
            Attributes = DefaultComputerAttributes
        },
        [OuGroups] = new DataPreparer
        {
            Data = activeDirectorySearcher.GetOuGroupPrincipals(
                CancellationToken),
            Attributes = DefaultGroupAttributes
        },
        [OuUsers] = new DataPreparer
        {
            Data = activeDirectorySearcher.GetOuUserPrincipals(),
            Attributes = DefaultUserAttributes
        },
        [OuUsersDirectReports] = new DataPreparer
        {
            Data = activeDirectorySearcher.GetOuUsersDirectReports(
                CancellationToken),
            Attributes = DefaultUserDirectReportsAttributes
        },
        [OuUsersGroups] = new DataPreparer
        {
            Data = activeDirectorySearcher.GetOuUsersGroups(
                CancellationToken),
            Attributes = DefaultUserGroupsAttributes
        }
    };
    return ouDataPreparers[QueryType];
}
```

That method creates all five `DataPreparer`s, each of which has an expensive method call in the `ActiveDirectorySearcher`. I would like to somehow only create the `DataPreparer` specified by the `QueryType` key, preferably without using `switch` or `if/else`. I changed from those to the `Dictionary` for the better formatting/style.

Comment: Why use a dictionary at all? Why not just a factory method method with a switch statement?

Comment: @AntP I mentioned in the question I wanted to avoid switches and if/elses for stylistic reasons.

Comment: I'm not sure what "stylistic reasons" they are but creating a collection of objects of which you only need one because the proper tool for the job doesn't look pretty seems a bit backward to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the type to be a `Func<DataPreparer>` so you will get a value factory and invoke it just later:

```
var ouDataPreparers = new Dictionary<QueryType, Func<DataPreparer>>
{
    [OuComputers] = () => new DataPreparer
    {
        Data = activeDirectorySearcher.GetOuComputerPrincipals(),
        Attributes = DefaultComputerAttributes
    },

    return ouDataPreparers[QueryType]();
}
```

In such a way, the object is created every time you query it.

If you want to create it once and keep the same instance like a singleton you can use `Lazy<DataPreparer>`:

```
var ouDataPreparers = new Dictionary<QueryType, Lazy<DataPreparer>>
{
    [OuComputers] = new Lazy<DataPreparer>(() => new DataPreparer
    {
        Data = activeDirectorySearcher.GetOuComputerPrincipals(),
        Attributes = DefaultComputerAttributes
    }),

    return ouDataPreparers[QueryType].Value;
}
```

Comment: Both of these options result in the warning "Implicitly captured closure: this". Thoughts?

Comment: I guess it is for `DefaultComputerAttributes` which is probably a variable on the object used in the lambdas.

Comment: All of the values assigned to `Attributes` are `static readonly Array`s. The warning is also only present on the `OuUsers` and `OuComputers` entries (the only two that don't take a `CancellationToken` parameter).

Comment: I tried to reproduce it, but it doesn't happen; we don't have enough details. You should start another question as this seems unrelated to the current one.

Comment: As long as you don't dispose the source of the CancellationToken you should be fine. Actually, the compiler might capture the CancellationToken for the closure, I can't double check now, but maybe some else will confirm, if so I would guess is due to a different issue.

Answer (score 6):

I would look into using a `Lazy<T>` for your `Data` property in your `DataPreparer` class.  That way, it only calls `activeDirectorySearcher.GetOuGroupPrincipals` if and when it's actually needed, instead of all at once at creation time.